# (ES6) class (ES2017) async / await getter

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Is it or will it be possible to have an ES6 class getter
return a value from an ES2017 await / async function.

```
class Foo {
    async get bar() {
        var result = await someAsyncOperation();

        return result;
    }
}

function someAsyncOperation() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('baz');
        }, 1000);
    });
}

var foo = new Foo();

foo.bar.should.equal('baz');
```

Comment: This is all you need: `get bar(){ return someAsyncOperation(); }`

Comment: @FelixKling I updated my post to hopefully clarify my question. I am not trying to return a function from the getter. I want the return value to come from an async operation.

Comment: Yes, `return someAsyncOperation();` returns the promise that `someAsyncOperation` returns. It doesn't return a function (what made you think that?)

Comment: I understand return someAsyncOperation(); would return a promise. I want to return the result of the promise. foo.bar should return 'baz'

Comment: It can't. You cannot return synchronously from an asynchronous function. `async/await` is just syntactic sugar around promises + generators. It lets you write code that *looks* synchronous, but it still runs asynchronously. At the top level you still have to deal with the promise. You might be able to do `await foo.bar`, but if not, you have to deal with the promise returned by `foo.bar` directly.

Comment: It would be nice if you could just do: `get async functionName(){}`. I'd like the ability to await inside of a getter (directly) instead of the round-about ways answered here.

Answer (score 69):

**Update:** As others have pointed out, this doesn't really work. @kuboon has a nice workaround in an answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53220336/2199393) here..

You can do this

```
class Foo {
    get bar() {
        return (async () => {
            return await someAsyncOperation();
        })();
    }
}
```

which again is the same as

```
class Foo {
    get bar() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            someAsyncOperation().then(result => {
                resolve(result);
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it won't return a result as Enki asked, but promise

Comment: This is exactly same to ```get bar(){ return someAsyncOperation() }```

Comment: Or `class Foo { get bar() { return (async () => await someAsyncOperation)() } }`

Answer (score 25):

You can get the value by `await` on the caller side.

```
class Foo {
    get bar() {
        return someAsyncOperation();
    }
}
async function test(){
  let foo = new Foo, val = await foo.bar;
  val.should.equal('baz');
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can only `await` promises, and `async` functions will return promises themselves.
Of course a getter can yield such a promise just as well, there's no difference from a normal value.

Answer (score 2):

For the value returned by the getter, this changes nothing, since an `async` function returns a `Promise` anyway. Where this matters, is in the function, since `await` can only be used in an `async` function.

If the issue it that `await` is wished in the function, I would do:

```
get property () {
  const self = this; // No closure with `this`, create a closure with `self`.
  async function f () { // `async` wrapper with a reference to `self`
    const x = await self.someFunction(); // Can use `await`
    // the rest with “self” in place of “this”
    return result;
  }
  return f(); // Returns a `Promise` as should do an `async get`
}
```