# Getter async typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a variable in typescript define as "getter", but the contect return be async like this;

```
class MyClass {
    async get isValid: boolean {
         return await myService.get("endPoint").value;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> 'async' modifier cannot be used here.

In typescript, it is possible to create asynchronous [getters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors)?

Comment: This can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879401/es6-class-es2017-async-await-getter

Comment: `return await myService.get("endPoint").value;` if this is the real code, what's the purpose? It's no different than having a regular getter and returning `return myService.get('endPoint').value`;